is it possible to boot into luks encrypted raw disk image with qemu/libvirt/virtualbox?
Done dd of my luks encryted drive, now im courious if its possible to create libvirt/quemu guest and attach that luks encrypted raw image and run it as is? Actually I have Fedora 38 on it with several partitions and usually on boot asks for luks password to decrypt drive.
method: created new guest in virt-manager with uefi boot and start it

There could be cases in which you can't get it to fully boot up successfully, just like when you "transfer" a drive from a machine to another. First of all, you may need to "register" the bootloader / boot manager to the emulated UEFI. First, because its EFI executable may not be installed to the "fallback path". Second, the initramfs may not contain the necessary driver to get the "real root" mounted, because the emulated host controller / block device are often of different type than what you had physically. (Also, is it a full drive image with an ESP and LUKS partition(s)?)

Is your system legacy BIOS boot or EFI? Is /boot encrypted or not?
